# Getting Number of Rows using Left Join

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables, one is comments, and another is likesordislikes

comments

```
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| id | userid |   usercom     | comname |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| 35 |      5 | check comment |      12 |
| 36 |      6 | comment test  |      12 |
| 37 |      6 | third comment |      12 |
| 38 |      5 | number four   |      12 |
| 39 |      7 | fifth         |      13 |
| 40 |      4 | 6th           |      13 |
| 41 |     18 | seven         |      13 |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
```

likesordislikes

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | vtype | uid  | comid |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 |     0 |    5 |    35 |
|  2 |     1 |    6 |    35 |
|  3 |     1 |    7 |    35 |
|  4 |     0 |    8 |    36 |
|  5 |     1 |    5 |    36 |
|  6 |     1 |    9 |    35 |
|  7 |     1 |   10 |    36 |
|  8 |     1 |   11 |    36 |
|  9 |     1 |   20 |    35 |
| 10 |     0 |    9 |    35 |
| 11 |     1 |   21 |    37 |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

- In *comments* table **userid** is session id (logged in user) and **comname** is the post unique id on which comments are made by logged in users.
- In *likesordislikes* table **vtype** is vote type where (0 = dislike , 1 = like), **uid** is logged in user id who likes or dislikes a comment and **comid** is from comments table (id) column

Now, i want to show total number of likes or dislikes under each comment for this specific comment.

the PHP code i am trying is here

```
$query1 = "SELECT
comments.id,
comments.usercom,
COUNT(likesordislikes.id) AS count
FROM
comments
LEFT JOIN likesordislikes ON
comments.id=likesordislikes.comid
WHERE likesordislikes.vtype='1'
GROUP BY
comments.id";

$query2 = "SELECT
comments.id,
comments.usercom,
COUNT(likesordislikes.id) AS count
FROM
comments
LEFT JOIN likesordislikes ON
comments.id=likesordislikes.comid
WHERE likesordislikes.vtype='0'
GROUP BY
comments.id";

$stmt = $DB->prepare($query1);
$stmt->execute();
$likes = $stmt->fetchAll();
$tlikes = count($likes);

$stmt = $DB->prepare($query2);
$stmt->execute();
$dislikes = $stmt->fetchAll();
$tdislikes = count($dislikes);

$slt = "SELECT * FROM `comments` where `comname` = '$c_name' and `post` = '$type'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $slt);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
echo $fetch['usercom']."<br />";
echo "Likes ".$tlikes."<br />";
echo "Dislikes ".$tdislikes;
}
```

that way, its not showing each comments likes/dislikes under that comment
in more clearer way, I want this result

> Comments:
>   check comment
>   Likes 4 - Dislikes 2
>
> comment test
>   Likes 3 - Dislikes 1
>
> third comment
>   Likes 1 - Dislikes 0
>
> number four
>   Likes - Dislikes
>
> fifth
>   Likes - Dislikes
>
> 6th
>   Likes - Dislikes
>
> seven
>   Likes - Dislikes

But its showing `Likes 4 - Dislikes 2` on each comment on the article 12

Can anyone please check whats wrong in it?

Comment: Your queries retrieve all comments along with (dis)likes and thus in the scope of the query, the COUNT is the total number of (dis)likes across all comments.

Comment: @Paul Well, Sir, how can i get total number of (dis)likes for each comment and echo them under that comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically getting all the likes and dislikes, for all the comments:

```
$query1 = "...";
$query2 = "...";
// ...
$tlikes = count($likes);
// ...
$tdislikes = count($dislikes);
```

And printing them for all the comments:

```
echo $fetch['usercom']."<br />";
echo "Likes ".$tlikes."<br />";
echo "Dislikes ".$tdislikes;
```

Which is why you're getting the same values for every comment. In order to fix your current code, you could create a map for `$likes` and `$dislikes`, like this:

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare($query1);
$stmt->execute();
$likes = array();
while($like = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
  $likes[$like['id']] = $like['count'];
}
```

And then, change your printing to something like:

```
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
  echo $fetch['usercom']."<br />";
  echo "Likes ".(empty($likes[$fetch['id']])?0:$likes[$fetch['id']])."<br />";
  // ...
}
```

Note: You probably should filter the likes and dislikes queries the same way you filter the comments query (so you don't ask for things you won't use)

An alternative way is changing your three queries for a single one, which would change your code to something like this:

```
$slt =
  "SELECT" .
    " c.usercom," .
    " SUM(CASE WHEN lod.vtype=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) likes," .
    " SUM(CASE WHEN lod.vtype=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dislikes" .
  " FROM" .
    " comments c LEFT JOIN likesordislikes lod ON lod.comid=c.id" .
  " WHERE" .
    " c.comname = '$c_name' AND c.post = '$type'" .
  " GROUP BY" .
    " c.id"
;
$res = mysqli_query($con, $slt);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
  echo $fetch['usercom']."<br />";
  echo "Likes ".$fetch['likes']."<br />";
  echo "Dislikes ".$fetch['dislikes'];
}
```

[Here you have the query](http://rextester.com/TLKGOS30459) in case you want to see it working

**Update**

If you don't want to show two zeros, you could change your `while` to something like:

```
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
  echo $fetch['usercom']."<br />";
  if($fetch['likes']==='0' && $fetch['dislikes']==='0'){
    $fetch['likes'] = '';
    $fetch['dislikes'] = '';
  }
  echo "Likes ".$fetch['likes']."<br />";
  echo "Dislikes ".$fetch['dislikes'];
}
```

Comment: I tried the last solution, it worked perfectly fine what i really want. but only a little thing left, if one comment has no likes/dislikes, then it should not show  `0` for example  `Likes - Dislikes` but if any comment has any likes but no dislikes, then it should show both values as  `Likes 5 - Dislikes 0`

Comment: I updated my answer to show you a simple way to achieve that

Comment: I loved it. Thank you very much for solving it. I ll get back to you if i will face any issue again. Thanks

Comment: Sir, I have asked another question because i am facing some other issues, i hope you can sort it out within seconds as i have tried full night and today as well, but all efforts in-vain. the question is  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185885/fetching-data-in-while-loop-by-using-left-join)

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked for you. You're welcome... I'm checking your other question, hopefully I'll be able to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks at the comname columns meaning it would give you everything for article 12 as you call it summed up and not separate for each of them.
You should be looking at the ids - something like

```
$slt = "SELECT * FROM `comments` where `id` = '$id' and `post` = '$type'";
```

where `$id` is the id in your comments table.
I am not sure how you can get this given the code you have shown but give it a try.

Comment: comname is the article unique id, if i will not show comments relevant to this article id, then all other comments will be shown to this article.