# Fetching data in while loop by using left join

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am fetching user comments from mysql table using while loop and want to put some condition class on buttons given in comment div.

Each comment has two buttons:

1. thumbsup button
2. thumbsdown button

I want to give a class name **active** if a user has already thumbed-up any comment so in case if in future, he clicks on the same comment's thumb-up, it will reverse the number of like.

i am discussing these two tables

comments

```
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| id | userid |   usercom     | comname |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
| 35 |      5 | check comment |      12 |
| 36 |      6 | comment test  |      12 |
| 37 |      6 | third comment |      12 |
| 38 |      5 | number four   |      12 |
| 39 |      7 | fifth         |      13 |
| 40 |      4 | 6th           |      13 |
| 41 |     18 | seven         |      13 |
+----+--------+---------------+---------+
```

likesordislikes

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | vtype | uid  | comid |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 |     0 |    5 |    35 |
|  2 |     1 |    6 |    35 |
|  3 |     1 |    7 |    35 |
|  4 |     0 |    8 |    36 |
|  5 |     1 |    5 |    36 |
|  6 |     1 |    9 |    35 |
|  7 |     1 |   10 |    36 |
|  8 |     1 |   11 |    36 |
|  9 |     1 |   20 |    35 |
| 10 |     0 |    9 |    35 |
| 11 |     1 |   21 |    37 |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

I am getting data from these tables and echoing that here...

```css
.vbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: none!important;
  color: inherit;
  color: #06C;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  font: inherit;
}

.like.active span {
  display: none;
}

.like.active:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f164";
  color: #009900;
}

.dislike.active span {
  display: none;
}

.dislike.active:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f165";
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```php
<?php
// ...
$sid = "18"; //session id
$c_name = "12"; //article-post id
$sel = "SELECT * FROM `likesordislikes` where `uid` = :sid AND `comid` = :comment";
if (isset($_POST['likes'])) {
  $comid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comid']);
  try {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sel);
    $stmt->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
    $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (count($fetch) == 0) {
      $insert = "INSERT INTO `likesordislikes` (`vtype` , `uid` , `comid`) VALUES " . "( :like, :likerid , :comment)";
      $stmt = $DB->prepare($insert);
      $stmt->bindValue(":like", "1");
      $stmt->bindValue(":likerid", $sid);
      $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comid);
      $stmt->execute();
    } elseif (count($fetch) > 0)  {
      if ($fetch[0]["vtype"] == "1") {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM `likesordislikes` where `uid` = :sid AND `comid` = :commnt";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($delete);
        $stmt->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
        $stmt->bindValue(":commnt", $comid);
        $stmt->execute();
      } elseif ($fetch[0]["vtype"] == "0") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `likesordislikes` SET  `vtype` =  '1' WHERE `uid` = :id AND `comid` = :commn";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $sid);
        $stmt->bindValue(":commn", $comid);
        $stmt->execute();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
}
if (isset($_POST['dislikes'])) {
  $comid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comid']);
  try {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sel);
    $stmt->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
    $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (count($fetch) == 0) {
      $insert = "INSERT INTO `likesordislikes` (`vtype` , `uid` , `comid`) VALUES " . "( :unlke, :likerid , :comment);";
      $stmt = $DB->prepare($insert);
      $stmt->bindValue(":unlke", "0");
      $stmt->bindValue(":likerid", $sid);
      $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comid);
      $stmt->execute();
    } else {
      if ($fetch[0]["vtype"] == "0") {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM `likesordislikes` where uid = :sid AND comid = :commnt";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($delete);
        $stmt->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
        $stmt->bindValue(":commnt", $comid);
        $stmt->execute();
      } elseif ($fetch[0]["vtype"] == "1") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `likesordislikes` SET `vtype` = '0' WHERE `uid` = :id AND comid = :commn";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $sid);
        $stmt->bindValue(":commn", $comid);
        $stmt->execute();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
}

$slt = "SELECT" .
" c.*," .
" SUM(CASE WHEN lod.vtype=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) likes," .
" SUM(CASE WHEN lod.vtype=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dislikes" .
" FROM" .
" comments c LEFT JOIN likesordislikes lod ON lod.comid=c.id" .
" WHERE" .
" c.comname = '$c_name' AND c.media = '$type'" .
" GROUP BY" .
" c.id";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $slt);

while($fetc = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
  //$select3 = "SELECT c.* FROM comments c LEFT JOIN likesordislikes lod ON c.id=lod.comid WHERE `uid` = :sid"; (It was my question code)
  $select3 = "SELECT vtype FROM likesordislikes WHERE comid = :commentid AND `uid` = :sid LIMIT 1"; // its the solution i got in answer
  try {
    $stmtt = $DB->prepare($select3);
    $stmtt->bindValue(":commentid", $fetc['id']); //update from the answer
    $stmtt->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
    $stmtt->execute();
    $vfetch = $stmtt->fetchAll();
    if (count($vfetch) == 0) {
      $likeclass = "";
      $dislikeclass = "";
    } 
    elseif (count($vfetch) > 0) {
      if ($vfetch[0]["vtype"] == "1") {
        $likeclass = "active";
        $dislikeclass = "";
      } 
      elseif ($vfetch[0]["vtype"] == "0") {
        $likeclass = "";
        $dislikeclass = "active";
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
  ?>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="div-right-mid">
      <span class="comment-text">
        <?php echo $fetc['usercom'] ?>  
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="rating-votes">
      <button class="vbtn like <?php echo $likeclass; ?>" value="<?php echo $comid ?>">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true">
          </i>
        </span>
      </button>
      <span class="likes">
        <font color="#6d7371">
          <?php echo $fetc['likes']; ?>
        </font>
      </span>&nbsp;
      <button class="vbtn dislike <?php echo $dislikeclass; ?>" value="<?php echo $comid ?>">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true">
          </i>
        </span>
      </button>
      <span class="dislikes">
        <font color="#6d7371">
          <?php echo $fetc['dislikes']; ?>
        </font>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

**Update** js

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.rating-votes').likeDislike({
  reverseMode: true,
  click: function (value, l, d, event) {
    var likes = $(this.element).find('.likes');
    var dislikes = $(this.element).find('.dislikes');
    var comid = $(".vbtn").val();
    var data = {comid:comid};
    if(value === 1){
       data.likes = true;
       }else{
       data.dislikes = true;
       }
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      type: 'POST',   
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        likes.text(parseInt(likes.text()) + l);
        dislikes.text(parseInt(dislikes.text()) + d);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
<script src="like-dislike.js"></script>
```

This php code is not giving me the required result.

I am facing Three issues...

1. When a user has thumbed-up a comment that thumb-up button is not showing active class **(Solved)**
2. Only the 1st comment's thumb-up/thumb-down is working on click, 2nd 3rd and all remaining comment's buttons are not working on click **(Solved)**
3. Ajax call is not sending data to php **(Edited)**

The CSS shows what happens to active class of thumbed up / thumbed down button for any specific comment by logged in user

Comment: `fetchAll` returns an array containing all of the result set rows. Where is the code that changes `aria-hidden` attribute value depending on the `$likeclass` value?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I am giving js code in question by updating it.

Comment: Do you have multiple of those `<div id="rating-votes">` elements?

Comment: @Piyin Yes Sir, because its in the while loop, if there are 5 comments in database, then 5 divs with the same id will be created including each comment in it. **Sorry** for the mistake in question, while loop was closed before comments div starts. now edited the question and closed while loop after comments div ends.

Comment: @JavedKhan Ok, then, that's another problem. I updated my answer to help you with `2` and `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your first question**

There are a couple of problems:

1. The `$select3` query is not bringing columns from the `likesordislikes` table (according to your code, you need the `vtype` column), it's only bringing `c.*` (which is all the fields from the `comments` table). Which is probably why you had to go with the `try...catch`, because it won't be able to find the `vtype` index. So that line of code should change to:

   ```
   $select3 = "SELECT c.*,lod.vtype FROM comments c LEFT JOIN likesordislikes lod ON c.id=lod.comid WHERE `uid` = :sid";
   ```
2. The `$select3` query is always getting all the `comments` records, even if the user didn't interact with those comments (because you're using a `LEFT JOIN`), and then picking the first one (index `0`) every time. Since you don't really seem to use information from the table `comments` (no need for the `JOIN`), and theoretically there should be a single record per user and comment, I'd change that line to:

   ```
   $select3 = "SELECT vtype FROM likesordislikes WHERE comid = :commentid AND `uid` = :sid LIMIT 1";
   ```

   And then, of course, bind the comment id:

   ```
   $stmtt->bindValue(":commentid", $fetc['id']);
   ```

**For your second question**

You're printing `<div id="rating-votes">` multiple times, which is invalid HTML-wise. The `id` attribute should be unique in the whole page, if you have two, calls like `$('#id')` will always give you a single element, the first one. So you should change the HTML code inside the `while` to use `class` instead of `id`, like this:

```
<!-- -->
<div class="rating-votes">
  <button class="vbtn like <?php echo $likeclass; ?>" value="<?php echo $comid ?>" class="vote">
    <!-- -->
  </button>
  <!-- -->
  <button class="vbtn dislike <?php echo $dislikeclass; ?>" value="<?php echo $comid ?>" class="vote">
    <!-- -->
  </button>
  <!-- -->
</div>
<!-- -->
```

Then, you should change your Javascript calls so they find by `class` instead of `id`, like this:

```
$('.rating-votes').likeDislike({    //.likeDislike function defined in like-dislike.js
  // ...
  click: function(value, l, d, event) {
    // ...
    var comid = $(this.element).find('.vote').val();
    // ...
  }
});
```

**For your third question**

The data is not arriving as you expect, probably because you're missing an ampersand (`&`), the code you have:

```
data: 'likes=' + likes + '&dislikes=' + dislikes + 'comid=' + comid,
```

would translate to something like:

```
data: 'likes=1&dislikes=2comid=3,
```

So you should change it to:

```
data: 'likes=' + likes + '&dislikes=' + dislikes + '&comid=' + comid,
```

Although I would recommend you use an object instead of concatenating the values yourself, that way jQuery will handle all the weird stuff for you. In order to do so, change that line to:

```
data:{
  likes:likes,
  dislikes:dislikes,
  comid:comid
}
```

- *Update*

<del>The other problem you have there, is you're sending the objects, not the objects' values, so, instead of:</del>

```
data:{
  likes:likes,
  dislikes:dislikes,
  comid:comid
}
```

<del>You should have:</del>

```
data:{
  likes:likes.val(),
  dislikes:dislikes.val(),
  comid:comid
}
```

- *Update*

The previous one wasn't really a problem, my bad. You shouldn't even send the values, since you're only using them as flags in PHP, so instead you should use something like:

```
data:{
  likes:true,
  comid:comid
}
```

Another problem is your PHP code is receiving both `likes` and `dislikes` (like the user hit both). Since that shouldn't be possible, I'd change the PHP from `if` then `if`, to `if` then `else if`, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['likes'])) {
  // ...
}else if (isset($_POST['dislikes'])) {
  // ...
}
```

Keep in mind, you're still sending both signals, so this way you'll always execute the first `if`. So you should change your Javascript so it only sends one of the two signals. I don't really know how `likeDislike` works, but your code should look something like:

```
// ...
var data = {
  comid:comid
};
if(theUserLikesIt){
  data.likes = true;
}else{
  data.dislikes = true;
}
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: data,
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, It Worked `$select3 = "SELECT vtype FROM likesordislikes WHERE comid = :commentid AND uid = :sid LIMIT 1";` For second issue i am updating js and php code in question. Kindly check php / js code, as ajax call is not sending data to php as well

Comment: Sir, 2nd issue is also solved, i got it. you explained me really very well. i will take care for this id and class stuff from now on. but 3rd issue is still remaining, i think while writing in question somehow removed `&` sign before `comid` infact i am using it already in that way `data: 'likes=' + likes + '&dislikes=' + dislikes + '&comid=' + comid,` but its not sending data still

Comment: Sir, I have tried it earlier, and now again on your suggestion  `data:{
  likes:likes,
  dislikes:dislikes,
  comid:comid
}` it even does not increase/decrease the likes/dislikes value on client side on clicking the thumb-up/down also it is not sending data to php as well.

Comment: Write `console.log(1);` right before the line `$.ajax({` and write `console.log(2);` right after the line `success: function(data) {`. Then trigger the event and check the console, if you see `1` it means your event is being called, if you see `2` it means the server responded

Comment: when i use `data: 'likes=' + likes + '&dislikes=' + dislikes + '&comid=' + comid,` console shows 1 and 2 and when i use `data:{ likes:likes, dislikes:dislikes, comid:comid }` it shows 1 and this error _Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery.js:4)
    at Vc (jquery.js:4)
    at Vc (jquery.js:4)
    at Vc (jquery.js:4)
    at Vc (jquery.js:4)
    at Vc (jquery.js:4)
    at Function.m.param (jquery.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:4)
    at LikeDislike.click (result=post.php?id=12&media=facts:673)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (like-dislike.js:125)_

Comment: Woah, hehe For things like that is why it's better to go for the object rather than the concatenation. I updated my answer so you can see the error

Comment: I changed it, now its not giving any error in console and showing 1 and 2, but still its not updating table records. i am calling ajax in `url: ''` empty url to send request on the same page. i hope it is not a problem?

Comment: Sir, I think i should not send the value to php, as i am updating its value already in php by inserting, updating or deleting `vtype` by checking `if (isset($_POST['likes'])) { insert, delete or update column vtype }`

Comment: You can remove the `1` and `2` now that we know it's getting there. The `url:''` works as you expect, you can even avoid setting it entirely and it should work. You are right about not sending the value, I updated my answer, hopefully it'll work

Comment: its still not working, i tried `if(likeBtn){` but not sending data to php and also, even not updating the (dis)likes numbers on client side with this code. i think i should edit question and post js code as well so you can see whats wrong in it. please check it, i am updating question with js.

Comment: According to the update you gave, you should be using `if(value === 1){`. Since you got `1` and `2`, the call is being done and answered. If it still doesn't work, try writing `console.log(data);` right after the line `success: function(data) {` and tell me what you see

Comment: Sir, Now its sending data to php, but there is a problem sending comid. User1 has commented, comid 1 and 2, User2 has commented comid 3 and 4. User1 can not like his own comments, So, when User1 likes/dislikes comid3 it updates record fine, but if he likes/dislikes comid4, it still updates comid3, same for the other user2, liking comid1 works fine, but liking comid2 updates comid1. so only 1st comment from other users is being updated does not matter which comment i am clicking on. its not sending comid properly. i am updating the div and js code in question please look whats my mistake

Comment: I got the issue, i am trying to get value of $comid to send it in php, but on the other hand, i am getting $comid if like/dislike is posted :D before clicking it, i am not getting any $comid

Comment: That's the spirit! Also, your line should read: `var comid = $(this.element).find('.vbtn').val();`, otherwise you'd be always getting the first one instead of the one you want

Comment: oh good gosh.... It worked perfectly fine. I was stuck in it for months. Finally it is Working. You are really great. Hats off... Thanks Piyin. You helped me alot. You are really superb not only in helping but behavior as well. Could have kissed you lolz... xD.

Comment: hehe Glad it worked. You're welcome. I'm not really that good, but we can all help each other :D haha That would be cool #nohomo xD

Comment: hahaha Thanks a bunch dear. Can i have your any of contact so could be in touch with you for future problems in case of my usual mistakes :(

Comment: haha No problem. Well, I don't see why not, here you go: goo.gl/CHcYWa